# Prevent WinForm AcceptButton handling Return key

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with a button hooked up to the `AcceptButton` property so that logic occurs and the form is closed when the user presses the Return key.

On that form I display a dynamically created `TextBox` that appears when the user double-clicks a certain area then hides when the user presses Return.

How do I prevent the form from processing the key press when the user presses Return while the `TextBox` has focus?

I was attempting to say the key press was handled in the `TextBox.KeyDown` event handler via `KeyEventArgs.Handled` but the `Button.Click` event of my accept button is being fired first...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `Enter` and `Leave` events of the `TextBox` to set the `AcceptButton` property to `null` (on `Enter`) and re-assign the button to it (on `Leave`).

Comment: It's effectively obvious but we are always in a situation where we are not sure if this is THE thing to do the workaround.

Comment: @Samuel: Because you posted your comment after I posted my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15108697/968531) below: This is IMHO not *the* thing to do, because no workaround is neccessary. IMHO it is *a* way to do it, but not *the* way ^^

Answer (score 18):

While resetting the Forms `AcceptButton` while the TextBox has focus will work, I believe that the more appropriate solution is to use the TextBoxes `AcceptsReturn` Property.

If you set

```
myTextBox.AcceptsReturn = true;
```

the Form will not accept on pressing RETURN, but your TextBox can handle this itself.

This will avoid the need to reset the AcceptButton in multiple places in your code.

Comment: So much better and elegant solution, +1!

Comment: This solution will only work if the 'Multiline' property of the TextBox is true.

Answer (score 5):

Set the `AcceptButton` property to null when you create that textbox, and set it back to the normal value when it loses focus:

```
var myTextBox = new TextBox ... ;
AcceptButton = null;

myTextBox.Leave += (s, e) => { AcceptButton = btnOK; };
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a complete working example, use the AcceptReturn=true of the TextBox as [NobodysNightmare suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761089/prevent-winform-acceptbutton-handling-return-key/15108697#15108697) and set the SuppressKeyPress to true to avoid bubble the event to the Form.
To use the AcceptButton you need to set/reset the AcceptButton property when you enter/leave the texbox as [Fredrik Mörk suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761089/prevent-winform-acceptbutton-handling-return-key/3761156#3761156).

```
var tb = new TextBox ...;  
IButtonControl _oldAcceptButton = null;  
tb.AcceptReturn=true;
tb.KeyDown += (s,e) => {
  if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter) {
    e.Handled=true;
    //will not inform any parent controls about the event.
    e.SuppressKeyPress=true;

    //do your own logic
    ....
  }
};
tb.Enter+=(s,e)=> {
  _oldAcceptButton = AcceptButton;
  AcceptButton = null;
};
tb.Leave+=(s,e)=>{
  AcceptButton = _oldAcceptButton;
};
```