# Excluding autocompleting textbox from form accept property?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form in which I've linked the accept property to a button called submit on the form so that whenever enter key is pressed on any control in the form it fires the submit button's click event. I also have an auto completing textbox (to/from) on the form with auto complete mode set to SuggestAppend. I want to move to the next control(textbox amount) when the user presses the enter key. I tried the textbox's keyup event like this:

```
private void tb_to_from_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Return)
            {
                tb_amount.Focus();
            }
        }
```

This moves the control to the other textbox, however, the submit button is also pressed. How do I exclude tb_to_from from the accept property of the form so that it just moves to the next control?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my answer as it as wrong. This is the proper answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761089/prevent-winform-acceptbutton-handling-return-key

Comment: @gcores Thank you that fixes my problem. I couldn't find this question. I'm new here and this was actually my first question, so should I delete the question now that I know it has been asked before or should I provide a link to that question?

Comment: I recommend deletion, but it's up to you.